# System wide mutex in Qt

Tags: qt, mutex

I have a process, and I'd like to check whether it is running or not, and take a decision in that direction, i.e., I'd like to check for running instances of this application, from another instance.

I can have 2 instances of the application running, dealing with 2 types of data. When a 3rd instance opens, it needs to check if another instance of its type ( from the 2 types already created ) is already running. If so, the new one needs to close down and send a message to the already running instance of its type.

Because of this, I think `QtSingleApplication` will not work.

I wish to create a System wide mutex and have the check done that way, but I've not seen any System wide mutex in Qt.

There is QMutex, which is only for threads of an application.

There is also something called `QSystemMutex` when I search online, but I suppose that's a custom solution? I didn't find it in my Qt installation or the assistant.

So is there any way I can create a System wide mutex using Qt, please?

Comment: Do you know why `QtSingleApplication` doesn't work??

Comment: I can have 2 instances of the application running, dealing with 2 types of data. When a 3rd instance opens, it needs to check if another instance of its type ( from the 2 types already created ) is already running. If so, the new one needs to close down and send a message to the already running instance of its type. QtSingleApplication will not work at all in this case.

Comment: It should work.  Don't you just need to set the appId parameter to the QtSingleApplication constructor based on the type?

Comment: It's more like this. I have an application, which can work with several types of data. Let's say an instance of the application is launched for type A. Then an instance of the application of type B. This is allowed. Now again, an instance of type A opens up. It needs to check whether an instance of type A is already running, and if so, pass on a message to it, and close down. All this can't be managed with `QtSIngleApplication`. So I thought, when type A is launched, create a System wide mutex of type A, and a shared memory. If another instance failed to create that mutex, it would close down.

Comment: Which is precisely what `QtSinglaApplication app("MyApp type A", argc, argv); if( app.isRunning() ) sendMessage("My Message");` ought to do.  Why are you so convinced it won't work?

Answer (score 0):

Mutexes are defined to be used as a object in one process. You are looking for a solution outside the process.

An simple solution would be to use the filesystem. Create a file and delete it when the process stops. This can be harder though when multiple processes are running from different directories or when the application crashes.

An more advanced solution is to use a shared memory object. These objects exist outside the process, and can be checked and modified from any process. An example on shared memory for QT can be found here:
http://doc.qt.digia.com/4.7-snapshot/ipc-sharedmemory.html

Comment: Sharing memory is fine as an IPC mechanism. I'll be using that to communicate with the running instances AFTER I've determined that an instance of a particular type is running. I thought of creating a system wide mutex with a particular name, then have the other instance of the same type try to create the same mutex. Once it fails, it knows that another instance of its type is running, and then it can attach to a shared memory and communicate and close down. But I need a system wide mutex for this.

Comment: Any mutex that would work across processes, would need IPC to do so. 

I googled some and found a class that does just that. It is in an QT extension library.  
http://docs.huihoo.com/qt/qtextended/4.4/qsystemmutex.html

Comment: I did see that..I've mentioned that in the original post. However, I was concerned about what sort of solution it is..whether part of Qt or not, and licensing issues..

Answer (score 0):

You can definitely do that with `QtSingleApplication`. Nothing obliges you to terminates if the application is already running. You can define a bootstrap protocol on top of what `QtSingleApplication` offer you, ie you use its api as a *locking primitive*.

What you can do is send a message with a specific type to the running instance, for example the string representation of the type. It is simple: You send a message to the running instance and he tells you if you are welcome or not.

- Each time an application starts, it listen to messages (even if there is one running). He can ack only one message if the type differs his.
- If there is no application running he goes straight to doing his job.
- If there is an application running, he send an *hello message* (his type for instance) and wait for ACK, NACK or timeout. You decide what to do if it timeouts.
- If you are waiting for a reply and you recieve an *hello*, you refuse.

ps: What you describe is not exactly a mutex. the following code

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
   QtSingleApplication app(argc, argv);

   if (app.isRunning())
       return 0;
   //blah blah blah
}
```

is already a mutex.